# netbeans: 'max' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, netbeans

Sorry if my question is very rudimentary.

I have a simple class defined as:

```
 #ifndef PAYOFF1_H 
 #define PAYOFF1_H 


class PayOff 
 { 
 public: 
 enum OptionType {call,put}; 
 PayOff(double Strike_,OptionType TheOptionType_); 
 double operator()(double Spot) const; 

 private: 
 double Strike; 
 OptionType TheOptionType; 
 };
```

and the source file is:

```
#include "PayOff1.h" 
 #include "minmax.h" 

 PayOff::PayOff(double Strike_, OptionType TheOptionType_) 
 : 
 Strike(Strike_),TheOptionType(TheOptionType_) 
 { 

 } 

 double PayOff::operator ()(double spot) const 
 { 
 switch(TheOptionType) 
 { 
 case call: 
 return max((spot - Strike) , 0); 

 case put: 
 return max((Strike-spot) , 0); 

 default: 
 throw("unknown option found."); 

 } 
 }
```

I get the error 'max' was not declared in this scope.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I think you should specify the namespace you are using, like this:

```
std::max
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

So, in the first case that part of code should look like this:

```
...
case call: 
return std::max((spot - Strike) , 0); 

case put: 
return std::max((Strike-spot) , 0); 
...
```

In the second case:

```
#include "PayOff1.h" 
#include "minmax.h" 
using namespace std;
...
```

Don't forget about namespace, it is important.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did add : "using namespace std;" and still same error. When I add std::max, I receive the error : 'max is not member of std" !! I am quite confused!

Comment: @QuantBreeze Good to see, you solved the problem. This "minmax.h" is strange, I've found some doc and it said that it includes <algorithm>, so I thought this is not the problem. Don't forget to check docs for the libs you are using, they are quite helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Replacing "minmax.h" with "algorithm" and using std::max. 
Thanks,